# Search Feature Parse IOS

Tags: ios, search, parse-platform

I would like to make a search feature that queries two different key from the same class.  What kind of regular expression could I use that return the most accurate values. Example:

```
 - (void)searchTableList {

[self.results removeAllObjects];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TC"];


CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.delegate.location coordinate];
PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude
                                              longitude:coordinate.longitude];

PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TC"];

[query1 setLimit:1000];
[query1 whereKey:@"location"
   nearGeoPoint:geoPoint
withinKilometers:5];
  [query1 whereKey:@"courses" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.searchBar.text    lowercaseString]]];

 [query1 whereKey:@"owner" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
 [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
   for( PFObject * object in objects)
   {
       [self.results addObject:object];
   }
 [query setLimit:1000];
 [query whereKey:@"location"
   nearGeoPoint:geoPoint
   withinKilometers:5];
     [query whereKey:@"owner" matchesRegex:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.searchBar.text lowercaseString]]];

   [query whereKey:@"owner" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    for( PFObject * object in objects)
    {
        [self.results addObject:object];
    }


   [self.tableView reloadData];
}];


}];
}
```

How could I take these two queries and order them in such a way that the most accurate information has priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find objects that match one of several queries, you can use **orQueryWithSubqueries:** method. For instance, if you want to find players with either have a lot of wins or a few wins, you can do:

```
PFQuery *lotsOfWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[lotsOfWins whereKey:@"wins" greaterThan:@150];

PFQuery *fewWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[fewWins whereKey:@"wins" lessThan:@5];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[fewWins,lotsOfWins]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
  // results contains players with lots of wins or only a few wins.
}];
```